# Spring Cloud Stream Function : Invoke Function<T,R> via REST call and output it to a KAFKA Topic

Tags: java, java-8, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have simple `@Bean` (Java 8 Functions) which are mapped to a destination `topic` (`-out` and `-in`).

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> transform() {
    return payload -> payload.toUpperCase();
}

@Bean
public Consumer<String> receive() {
    return payload -> logger.info("Data received: " + payload);
}
```

**.yml config:**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: transform;receive
      bindings:
        transform-out-0:
          destination: myTopic
        receive-in-0:
          destination: myTopic
```

Now, I want to invoke the `transform` function via a `REST` call so that it's output goes to the `destination topic` (i.e. `transform-out-0` mapped to `myTopic`) and is picked up by the `consumer` from this destination (`receive-in-0` mapped to `myTopic`). Basically, every REST call should spawn a new instance of a *KAFKA* `Producer` and close it.

How can I achieve this please using `spring-cloud-stream` ?

Thanks

Angshuman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `StreamBridge` instead of having that `transform` function. This is the new recommended approach for dynamic destinations in Spring Cloud Stream.
Here is the basic idea:

```
@Autowired
private StreamBridge streamBridge;

@RequestMapping
public void delegateToSupplier(@RequestBody String body) {
    streamBridge.send("transform-out-0", body);
}
```

and then provide this property through configuration -  `spring.cloud.stream.source: transform`

Spring Cloud Stream will create an output binding called `transform-out-0` for you. Each time the REST endpoint is called, through `StreamBridge`, you will send the data to the destination topic.

For more info see [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streambridge).

Comment: Ah, thanks. So, say, I am a message listener on IBM MQ and I want to forward the message to KAFKA, I will use `StreamBridge` ? Is this also the recommended way of invoking a `Producer` directly (in native api, we do Producer.send(...)?  

Otherwise, I see that `Supplier` bean gets called infinitely at 1sec interval always. I had replaced the `transform` with `Supplier<T>` and noticed, that getting polled continuously.

Comment: If you are a listener on MQ and want to forward the message to Kafka, you don't need `StreamBridge`. A simple function approach should work as shown with your original code. You don't need to directly deal with `Producer`, that is handled for you by Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder. Nothing prevents you from using the producer API directly though, but i don't see the need for your use case.

Comment: As to your second question about `Supplier`, you can control the polling frequency using the properties listed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/DefaultPollerProperties.java

Comment: thanks. I get the supplier polling part now.

Sorry, I am a bit lost on MQ message forwarding. So, for any `Foreign event-driven sources`, be it REST or MQ listener, doc says, use `streambridge`. With my above functional approach, how will it forward to Kafka Topic without `streambridge` ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the MQ part. That is kind of a source (supplier) that you want to take an action upon. `StreamBridge` or `Supplier` should work in that case.

Comment: Thank you. 
I think you meant, I can use `Supplier` if I rewrite `MQ` code with new Functional Pattern (`-in , -out`). But, to plug my existing `MQ` with `KAFKA`, I will need to route it via `streambridge`. Would be great if there is any sample which depicts where I can mix Functional pattern of Spring and use raw Kafka api as well.

Comment: I want to call rest endpoint after consumer consumes from topic. How can this be done in spring Spring cloud stream.

Comment: You can use `StreamBridge` directly inside the consumer method.